# Getting the value of an attribute inside a <td> with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have the following jQuery:

```
$.fn.dataTableExt.afnSortData['dom-text'] = function (oSettings, iColumn) {
    var aData = [];
    $('td:eq(' + iColumn + ') input', oSettings.oApi._fnGetTrNodes(oSettings)).each(function () {
        aData.push(this.value);
    });
    return aData;
}
```

I'm using this to get the **value** of the **input** in td elements.

However my HTML now looks like this:

```
<td id="tempRowKey_117" class=" sorting_1" data-rk="100001">  
   <input type="text" value="10.0.1" id="TempRowKey_117">
</td>
```

How can I change my jQuery so that it now gets the **value of data-rk** instead of the value of the input?

In other words I want to get "10001"

Comment: Have you tried changing the selector to `$('td:eq(' + iColumn + ')'` and pushing the value as `aData.push($(this).data('rk'));`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$.fn.dataTableExt.afnSortData['dom-text'] = function (oSettings, iColumn) {
    var aData = [];
    $('td:eq(' + iColumn + ')', oSettings.oApi._fnGetTrNodes(oSettings)).each(function () {
        aData.push($(this).attr('data-rk'));
    });
    return aData;
}
```